# how custom service use in custom directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I tried creating a simple form with two custom directives and a service. I created two custom directives. One for the form and the other for displaying the output data. I got stuck with the custom service side. I don't know how to write the service in my application. I am totally confused.

Can anyone help me ?

My JS file looks like this:

```
angular.
    module('myApp', []).

    factory('myService', function () {
        return {
            thing: function () {
                console.log('It\'s working');
            }
        };
    }).

    controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, myService) {
        $scope.formHead = 'Angular JS Form';
    }]).

    controller('ctrl2', '$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        { myService(list); };
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.Fname = '';
        $scope.submitTheForm = function () {
            if ($scope.Fname && $scope.age && $scope.place && $scope.sex) {
                $scope.list.push(this.Fname, this.Lname, this.age, this.sex, this.place);
                $scope.Fname = '';
                $scope.Lname = '';
                $scope.age = '';
            }
        };
    }]).

    directive('formAjs', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'formDirective.html'
        };
    }).

    directive('outputAjs', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E', 
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.list = [];
                this.submitTheForm = function () {
                    $scope.list.push(this.Fname);
                };
            },
            link: function (scope, element, ctrl2) {
                console.log(scope.list);
            },
            templateUrl: 'outputAjs.html'
        };
    });
```

Comment: I suggest that you post what you have tried (specifics), and what isn't working vs what your expectations and understanding are.

Comment: angular.module("myApp", [])
.factory('myService',function () {
      return{
        thing:function(){
            console.log("Its working");
        }    };    })
  .controller("ctrl",['$scope',function($scope,myService){
          $scope.formHead="Angular JS Form";  
    }])

Comment: .controller("ctrl2",'$scope','myService',function($scope,myService)
      {{
    myService(list);};
     $scope.list=[];
                  $scope.Fname='';
            $scope.submitTheForm=function(){
               if($scope.Fname && $scope.age && 
                       $scope.place && $scope.sex){
                        $scope.list.push(this.Fname,this.Lname,
                        this.age,this.sex,this.place);
                $scope.Fname='';
                $scope.Lname='';
               $scope.age='';}};  
        }])

Comment: .directive('formAjs', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'formDirective.html'
              };  })
        .directive('outputAjs',function(){
            return {
                restrict:'E',
          controller:function($scope,$element,$attrs){
              $scope.list=[];
             this.submitTheForm=function(){
                  $scope.list.push(this.Fname);
              };},
        link:function(scope,element,ctrl2){
         console.log(scope.list);
         }, templateUrl :  'outputAjs.html'   
                
            };  
        });

Comment: You might want to add these to your original post. Would be much more readable:)

Comment: @Sims: Seriously, there are so many problems with this code that I don't know where to start. Please, try to clean this up and come back with a specific problem regarding some feature (and not the code itself).

Comment: Yes I know. my problem is :..I created a form inputting some data like username,age,gender..and a submit button is there.I used a controller and a directive for this form.I am trying to get the data from the form and want to output it through another directive say outputajs.html with another controller.i want to use a service for this. But I am struck with this part of doing service and connecting the two controllers..I mean how to write a service and communicating with the controllers or directives....please help me...i just want to get the flow of angularjs by doing this form.